# Checkbox wrong item selected html

Tags: jquery

I have a html checkbox with multiple options.

I'm using JQuery to change the 'Reveal Answer' section which is interactive to what the user selects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('input[type="checkbox"].Q1').click(function() {
    checkQ1();
  });

  function checkQ1() {

    var MCQ10_checked = $('input[value="AQN10"]').prop('checked');
    var MCQ11_checked = $('input[value="AQN12"]').prop('checked');

    if (MCQ10_checked && MCQ11_checked) {
      $("#CA1").html("This is right");
      return;
    }

    if (MCQ10_checked || MCQ11_checked) {
      $("#CA1").html("This is a little right");
      return;
    }

    $("#CA1").html("This is wrong");

  }
});
</script>
```

Currently, if the a user selects an incorrect option as well as both correct options, it still says it's right.

I would like this to default to 
"It's a little bit right" option instead because they have also selected an incorrect option.

Any advise on this would be appreciated

Comment: Is this really a "php" question?

Comment: I guess not, sorry I'm using php to create the code but for this question it isn't relevant.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Which options are correct and incorrect?

Comment: Your code only checks to see if both correct answers are checked. So even if 100 checkboxes are checked and also 2 correct ones are checked. it will say it's right. You have to check the checked value of other checkboxes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count all the checkboxes that were checked. If it's not 2, then they must have checked other boxes beside the correct ones that they checked.

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[type="checkbox"].Q1').click(function() {
    checkQ1();
  });

  function checkQ1() {
    var checked_count = $(":checkbox.Q1:checked").length;
    var MCQ10_checked = $('input[value="AQN10"]').prop('checked');
    var MCQ11_checked = $('input[value="AQN12"]').prop('checked');

    if (MCQ10_checked && MCQ11_checked && checked_count == 2) {
      $("#CA1").html("This is right");
      return;
    }

    if (MCQ10_checked || MCQ11_checked) {
      $("#CA1").html("This is a little right");
      return;
    }

    $("#CA1").html("This is wrong");

  }
});
```